# How to return a dataframe as a datatable item on a shiny app

Tags: dataframe, shiny, datatables-1.10

in the following code I managed to return the result of a data summary as a printed text, however I want to return it in a datatable and I never get the wanted result can anyone be of my help?

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
      fileInput('file1', 'Upload your  CSV File'),
      htmlOutput("variables"),
      numericInput(inputId="n", label="n", value=4, min=3,step=1),
      htmlOutput("facteurs"),
      verbatimTextOutput("res"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("Tab")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  myData1 <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,row.names=1)
    data
  })
  output$variables <- renderUI({
    req(myData1())
    df_init <- myData1() 
    for(i in c(1:ncol(df_init))){
      if((class(df_init[,i])=="integer") && length(unique(df_init[,i]))<=input$n){df_init[,i]<-factor(df_init[,i])}}
    x=sapply(df_init,class)
    x=(x=="numeric")
    df=df_init[,x]
    if (identical(df, '') || identical(df,data.frame())) return(NULL)
    selectInput(inputId = "V1", label = "Variables to use: Y", choices=names(df), selected=names(df[1]))
  })
  output$facteurs <- renderUI({
    req(myData1())
    df_init <- myData1() 
    for(i in c(1:ncol(df_init))){
      if((class(df_init[,i])=="integer") && length(unique(df_init[,i]))<=input$n){df_init[,i]<-factor(df_init[,i])}}
    x=sapply(df_init,class)
    x=(x=="factor")
    df=df_init[,x]
    if (identical(df, '') || identical(df,data.frame())) return(NULL)
    selectInput(inputId = "F1", label = "Factors to use: X", choices=names(df), selected=names(df))


  })
  output$res<-renderPrint({
    data<-myData1()
    if (is.null(data)) return("Enter your data!")
    v=c(input$V1,input$F1)
    x=data[,v]
    print(tapply(x[,1],x[,2],summary)) 
  })
  output$Tab<-renderDataTable({
    data<-myData1()
    if (is.null(data)) return("Enter your data!")
    v=c(input$V1,input$F1)
    x=data[,v]
    DT::datatable(data=tapply(x[,1],x[,2],summary))
  })
  }


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also add to this reproducible code a data sample so you can verify its functionalities

```
,Var,Lo,ES,Acidity,K232,K270,IP,OS,C 14:0,C 16:0,C 16:1,C 17:0,C 17:1,C 18:0,C 18:1,C 18:2,C 18:3,C 20:0,C 20:1,total,LLL,LnLO,LnLP,LLO,LnOO,PLL,LOO,LOP,PLP,OOO,POP,POO,AOL,SOO,SOP,Chlorophyll,b carotène,polyphenols ,Ethyl acetate,2- Methyl butanal,3- Methyl butanal,1-Penten-3-one,3-Hexanone,Hexanal,3-Pentanol,Trans-2-pentenal,1-Penten-3-ol,Cis-3-hexenal,Trans-2-hexenal,1-Pentanol,Hexyl acetate,Cis-3-hexenyl acetate,Cis-2-pentenol,6-Methyl-5-hepten-2-one,1-Hexanol,Trans-3-hexenol,Cis-3-hexenol,Trans-2-hexenol,Acetic acid,Butyric acid,H-   Tyr      ,Tyr ,DFOA,DFLA,Ac-Pin,Pin,EAA,OA,LA,total phenols (HPLC)
P1,chetoui,beja,sp,0.93,1.49,0.2,9.2,16.51,0.01,13.5,0.57,0.07,0.08,2.57,67.04,18.56,1.16,0.02,0.39,103.95,0.72,0.45,0.1,7.87,2.63,0.38,22.14,8.8,0.7,33.47,15.84,1.77,0.37,3.95,0.8,5.05,4.1,491.6,2.72,0.29,0.11,0.08,0.1,15.27,1.35,1.55,3.77,22.68,133.13,0.36,9.92,7.14,2.37,0.5,10.03,0.78,121.11,14.12,0.05,0.08,1.91,4.15,10.33,40.52,1.21,5.5,2.92,30.65,2.35,99.53
P2,chetoui,beja,sp,0.36,1.24,0.2,8.2,16.81,0.01,13.39,0.18,0.05,0.07,1.23,69.23,18.63,0.91,0.02,0.28,104,0.69,0.43,0.15,7.81,2.57,0.42,22.21,8.84,0.71,33.87,15.6,2.01,0.38,4.14,1.01,5.88,6.161,457.04,2.52,0.34,0.12,0.09,0.22,15.2,1.32,1.52,3.67,22.61,133.19,0.35,9.89,7.18,2.34,0.51,10.17,0.75,121.21,14.29,0.05,0.02,1.92,4.05,10.45,40.63,1.25,5.55,2.95,31.042,2.17,100.01
P3,chetoui,beja,sp,0.84,1.87,0.21,8.6,16.73,0.01,13.31,0.45,0.06,0.08,2.54,69.29,17.03,0.84,0.02,0.37,104,0.72,0.42,0.12,7.82,2.61,0.43,21.22,8.83,0.72,33.85,15.52,1.92,0.39,4.05,0.95,5.92,6.241,482.12,2.72,0.25,0.08,1.12,0.42,15.01,1.3,1.44,3.93,22.51,133.07,0.39,9.87,7.16,2.31,0.52,10.1,0.76,121.29,14.21,0.06,0.01,1.93,4.12,10.6,40.71,1.26,5.54,2.96,30.43,2.26,99.81
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not very clear on what you need your output to look like, so here's one way to do it:

```
output$Tab<-renderDataTable({
    data<-myData1()
    if (is.null(data)) return("Enter your data!")
    v=c(input$V1,input$F1)
    x=data[,v]
    do.call(cbind, tapply(x[,1],x[,2], summary))
  })
```

or if you'd like it transposed change the `cbind` to `rbind`

Comment: Thank you so much that what I exactly needed